# AwsIotProvider SDK and Amplify get topic name in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, aws-iot

I need to get topic subscribed about payload received from topic subscription in angular 13.

So this is what i receive

[image]

I need to get Symbol(topic)

I've tried like this:

```
let topic = msg.value['Symbol(topic)']
```

like this:

```
let topic = msg.value.topic
```

but always undefined...how can get the topic name inside Symbol(topic) variable.?

Thanks